# getElementsByTagName of all siblings

Tags: getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

UPDATE:

Let me rephrase.

I have multiple divs that all contain, among other things, an img element with the class="yes". But they're not all the same siblings.

Two examples:

```
<div id="div1" onclick="function(this)">
  <img src="image1" />
  <div>
    <img src="image2" class="yes" />
  </div>
</div>


<div id="div2" onclick="function(this)">
  <img src="image3" class="yes" />
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to formulate one function for both divs that would change the source of the image with class yes.

getElementsByTagName doesn't seem to do the trick, nor does getElementsbyClassName.

Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: Look into jQuery and it's [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/?s=selector).

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagname is the wrong function.

There is no easy way to do what you're trying to do, unless you resort to third party libraries such as jQuery.

With jquery, you use this code:

```
$('img.yes').each(function() {
   console.log(this);
});
```

Here is a working example of what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYBp6/

Comment: I have jQuery installed, but this line of code returns an error - as in it breaks off the function...

Comment: See my updated answer and jsfiddle example (ps: next time it's a good idea to post a jsfiddle with the html/javascript that you're actually using).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) like this:

```
function some_function(x)
{
    var arr = $("#" + x.id + " .yes"); // Gets all children of the class "yes"
}
```

Or if you only want to get img elements, you can do this instead:

```
function some_function(x)
{
    var arr = $("#" + x.id + "img.yes");
}
```

In both of these examples, arr would contain DOM elements, and not the kind of "element" produced by jQuery normally.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
function function(x) {
  $(x).find('.yes').attr('src','differentimage.png');
}
```

Comment: If it works for you then you should tick the "accept" button for your answer. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question. I do it all the time.

Comment: I doesn't let me - yet. Will do when it does.